# jQUery --> After window resize scroll to section does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, window-resize

After window resize my scroll function **does not work as I described below (description shows how I want it to work)**:

1. I do window resize.
2. After window resize when I click the given menu item the window should scroll to...
3. corresponding to that menu item section offset().top-45 for max-width:480px (first breakpoint)
4. corresponding to that menu item section offset().top-90px for min-width 481px (second breakpoint)

https://jsfiddle.net/d1abevro/1/

It only works as expected for a given breakpoint without window resize (onload).

```
  function displaymenu() {


   if ($(window).width() <= 480) {

              $('.c-main-menu ul').css({display: 'none'});      

           $(document).on("click", "a.c-main-menu__link", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
               $('html,body').animate({
                      scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top-56
                  }, 800); 
                  $('.c-main-menu ul').slideToggle();  
            });    
              $('.c-nav .menu-trigger').click(function() {
                $('.c-nav .c-main-menu ul').slideToggle();
              });        

         } else {

       $('.c-main-menu ul').css({display: 'block'});         
            $(document).on("click", "a.c-main-menu__link", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top-90
                }, 800);        
             });
                }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is caused because after each resize you append a new event. You should kill the old event an create a new one in order to prevent conflict with the old event. To get this approach the best way is to adding a namespace for your event, for example:

```
$(document).on("click.menuLinkEvent",".my_links", function(){});
```

And before adding the new event kill any old event it using unbind method and passing the event with the namespace:

```
$(document).unbind("click.menuLinkEvent");
```

Also looks like you understand correctly that the event will be appended each time after resize so you added a setTimeout function, but forgot to add a time, so however it will fire inmediately.

I made some changes to [your fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/d1abevro/2/). Let me know if it works as you expect

Comment: Thank you it looks better. However, another issue emerged with .menu-trigger').click(function() namely with slideToggle -->it goes like this: 1. I start with onload min-width:481px breakpoint --> works fine (as described in original post) 2. I do window resize to max-width:480px --> works fine (as described in original post) 3. Again, I do window resize but within the realm of mmax-widh:480px (for instance to 380px), then I click .menu-trigger, and the function slideToggle fires 2 times (openes and closes). Probably its because "That is caused because after each resize you append a new event..

Comment: That is because you have two events to open/close the menu. Kill the event propagation so the other events wont be executed. Check line 20 https://jsfiddle.net/d1abevro/3/